# (click) event don't work in string angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My function don't call when i clicked in tag a
i have the next code in my component

```
public htmlstr: string;
public idUser:number;

this.idUser = 1;
this.htmlstr = `<a (click)="delete(idUser)">${idUser}</a>`;

public delete(idUser){
    alert("id " + idUser);
}

my html

<div [innerHTML]="htmlstr"></div>
```

but the function delete don't call and not show the alert

Comment: maybe try ${idperson} instead of {{idperson}}

Comment: I already tried that form but it did not work

Comment: did you find any solution of it?

Answer (score 0):

Angular string interpolation braces won't work in a variable like this.

You could use `template literals` (note the backticks, not single quotes):

```
this.iduser = `<a style="font-weight: bold;"> id: ${idperson} </a>`
```

Or `String.format`:

```
this.iduser = '<a style="font-weight: bold;"> id: {} </a>'.format(idperson)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Angular 4 so why not simply use interpolation?

Your code would thus look something like this:

```
idLabel = 'id: ';
id: number;
```

And then your template would look like this:

```
<span>
  <a style="font-weight:bold;" href="#">{{idLabel + id}}</a>
</span>
```

Ideally, if you are using a router for this link you could attach the `routerLink` diractive to the anchor tag like so:

```
<a style="font-weight:bold;" [routerLink]="'/user/' + id"></a>
```

...or whatever your route configuration looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    this.idperson = 1;
    this.iduser = `<a style='font-weight: bold;'> id: ${idperson} </a>`;
```

Note that i'm using backquote, no simple quote. The result will be:

```
id: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using AOT it might be as simple as making the function public?

also check your browser's console for errors

Comment: the function is public, and i don't have errors in console